# Georeference .txt file to SpatialGridDataFrame

Tags: r, grids-graticules

I have a matrix file in a .txt format and I want to georeference this matrix using latitude and longitude.
How could I do this in R, so that I can transform my .txt file into a `SpatialGridDataFrame` object and then import it in GRASS GIS?